# Trigger is not firing when previous value is null

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, oracle11g

I am inserting old and new values to audit trail table using trigger when a change happens in the master table.

```
create or replace TRIGGER audit_trg
  BEFORE UPDATE ON Employee
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF( UPDATING( 'E_AGE' ) )
  THEN
  IF(NVL(:OLD.E_AGE,0)!=NVL(:new.E_AGE,0))
  THEN
   INSERT INTO AUDIT_TRAIL( ID,PRIMARY_KEY,TABLENAME,COLUMNNAME,OLDVALUE,NEWVALUE,UPDATEDDATETIME,UPDATEDBY ,DESCRIPTION)
      VALUES(AUDIT_TRAIL_SEQ.NEXTVAL,:new.ID,'Employee','E_AGE',NVL(:OLD.E_AGE,0),:new.E_AGE,sysdate, :new.UPDATEDBY,:new.DESCRIPTION );
  END IF;
  END IF;
END;
```

But it is not inserting any values to Audit trail table only if the previous value is null.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
if nvl( :old.e_age, 0 ) != nvl( :new.e_age, 0 )
```

You want to get rid of the `NULL` from both sides of the comparison.

EDIT: This is my test of the trigger. Rows 1 and 4 are a "no change" condition and the Trail column should remain unchanged with a zero value. The rest represent a change: from one value to another(2), from a value to NULL(3) and from NULL to a value(5). For these rows, the Trail value should be the OldAge/NewAge value. And they are.

```
drop table TestEmp;
create table TestEmp(
    id      int,
    e_age   int,
    NewVal  int,
    Trail   int default 0
);

insert into TestEmp( id, e_age, NewVal )
    select  1, 10, 10 from dual union all
    select  2, 10,  8 from dual union all
    select  3, 10, null from dual union all
    select  4, null, null from dual union all
    select  5, null, 10 from dual;

create or replace TRIGGER audit_trg
  BEFORE UPDATE ON TestEmp
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF UPDATING( 'E_AGE' ) THEN
        IF NVL( :OLD.e_age, 0 ) != NVL( :new.e_age, 0 ) THEN
            :new.Trail := :new.e_age;
        END IF;
    END IF;
END;
/
select * from TestEmp;
update TestEmp set e_age = NewVal;
select * from TestEmp;
```

Before update:

```
ID   E_AGE NewVal TRAIL
 1      10     10     0
 2      10      8     0
 3      10 <null>     0
 4  <null> <null>     0
 5  <null>     10     0
```

After update:

```
ID   E_AGE NewVal TRAIL
 1      10     10     0
 2      10      8     8
 3  <null> <null> <null>
 4  <null> <null>     0
 5      10     10    10
```

So the `if` statement was entered for rows 2, 3, 5 -- as expected.

Comment: Tried , But still it is not inserting values

Comment: Don't know what to say. See my test.

Comment: Couple of possibilities: (1) If you happen to update a NULL value to 0, the condition will evaluate to FALSE and no audit record will be inserted.  (2) If you are using multiple sessions, ensure that the update transaction is committed before querying the audit log; the trigger's insert occurs in the same transaction as the update.

Comment: A couple of answers: (1) whenever you convert a null to a testable value, you must select a value outside the normal range expected in the context of the test. If *all* values are possibilities, you finally have to just use `if a is null and b is null`. (2) That depends on how you want the log action to be handled. Sometimes you want the log entry to be rolled back or committed with the DML, sometimes you want the log entry to remain even if the DML operation is rolled back. That was not part of the question.

Answer (score -1):

I am having similar issues, before update trigger is not creating any history when the value is changing from null to a value. My logic is working for any changing except for the null values

if nvl(:old.price,null) <> nvl(:new.price,null) then
     insert into bla bla....
        values (......);
   end if;

Comment: hmm ... doesn't look like an answer to me, is it?

Comment: `NVL(x, NULL)` is a pointless operation - it is the same as just saying `x`.  The inequality will still always evaluate to FALSE if either of the two expressions is NULL.  You want to use some non-NULL expression to make the test work, e.g. `NVL( x, 0 )`.